# How can I determine start and stop points for mouse cursor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, mouseevent

Let's say the user starts to move mouse and stop at somewhere on the browser. How can I determine start and stop point with Javascript/jQuery?

Start point is easy, I can get it with `mousemove` event but what about stop point?

I can't use `mouseenter` or `mouseleave` events because my playground is window or document itself.

Comment: You should set a timer on mousemove, and if the mouse hasn't moved in 500ms, you know that that is the end position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using a combination of setTimeout and clearTimeout. 
If the user doesn't move for x amount of seconds then it means that he stopped.

Here I wrote you an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lastMove = 0;
    var lastTimeout = 0;
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
            $('#status').html(e.pageX + ', ' + e.pageY);
            var currentMove = (new Date()).getTime();
            if (lastTimeout != 0) {
                clearTimeout(lastTimeout);
            }
            if (currentMove - lastMove > 1500)
            { alert('started'); }
            lastMove = currentMove;
            lastTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                var currentMove = (new Date()).getTime();
                if (currentMove - lastMove > 1500)
                { alert('stopped'); }
            }, 1510);
        });
    })
</script>
<h2 id="status">
0, 0
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

The start location is the location when the mousemove event is first fired. It will keep firing until the mouse stops moving. So, if you add a timer (setTimeout/clearTimeout) to your mousemove event function, you can say the mouse has stopped moving after a certain amount of time has passed without the mousemove function being called.