# Detecting mouse coordinates with precision

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mouseevent

After a sleepness night I discovered something about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646825/how-to-detect-when-mouse-has-stopped) which I think is fundamentally mind boggling, at least to me.

Mouse coordinates **ARE NOT PRECISE** (I guess at a high speed of processing where the whole canvas has to be recreated when movement occurs) as in my codes above. I have tested this code piece by piece and discovered that the problem is not in my loop, but in the precision of

```js
if ((newMouseX !== mouseX) && (newMouseY !== mouseY)).
```

If you tested this part of code by slower times (which will allow your eyes to detect the difference in coordinates when 'it stops', then you will realise that `newMouseX` & `mouseX` are off by 1-2 pixel 90% of the time, > 2 pixel 9% of the time, and only equal about 1% of the time. (I did not measure the statistics but that is what I picked on several rounds of testing).

*I can't get it to work in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vEqj/) but I think you can copy it to your testing ground to see what I mean. If you can get it to work in fiddle it would be great so experts can give it a short :)*

This means that the mouse is considered to be 'moving' by my code even when it should have 'stopped', and thus 'stops' several times in between, therefore calling the loop too many times in a second, which is the problem I have been having.

I would be happy to hear comments from other experts, including those who can test this and come up with a statistical precision/advice.

My advice, and solution for the moment, is to consider movement when the difference is more than 10 pixels of either coordinates. Of course this presents a problem, but I can leave with that until some better solution comes up.

so instead of

```js
if ((newMouseX !== mouseX) && (newMouseY !== mouseY))
```

i have used

```js
if (( Math.abs(newMouseX - mouseX) > 10) || ( Math.abs(newMouseY != mouseY) > 10) )
```

Another thing to consider is how to deal with the mouse position when it goes off my target canvas area... that looks like an infinite movement at the moment!

**The Question:**

How can I get the precise mouse coordinates so I can compare `mouseX` & `newMouseX`?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think your code makes much sense.  You've got a **mousemove** event listener. By definition, that event will fire *when the mouse moves*.  If the mouse has not moved, then the event handler won't fire.

Comment: Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3vEqj/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mouse *precision* is determined by the hardware. A high-precision mouse will produce different results than a built-in mouse pad for instance (not to mention touch devices).

However, this is not the problem with your code and your scenario. You are only listening to the `mousemove` event. It will by definition only throw an event when you move the mouse - hence the new mouse position can never be at the same position as the previous one. That would be impossible and should be off by 100% (unless you are triggering two+ moves where the last goes back to the fist position before you check).

Normally one would listen to the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events as well as they are not dependent on a mouse *move* to trigger. Detecting start and stop solely based on mouse movement is considered impossible under all possible circumstances.

You can do a compromise and make a definition of what a start is and what a stop is, ie. if the mouse has not moved after x milliseconds it is considered a stop (start would be on first move).

This means you will need to follow this rule every time you need to detect a stop. Imaging doing a drawing and sometimes you draw sometime slow other times fast. Or, how do you move the mouse to a new position without drawing anything... There is a good reason for the mouse button(s) to be invented :-)

The rule will soon prove to be useless (or overly complicated prone to more than one error).

As to mouse positions outside canvas there are several ways to handle this.

You can get the canvas bounds by calling:

```
var canvasRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
```

which gives you [properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMClientRect) to check when mouse position is inside or outside this rectangle.

Another way is to listen to the `mouseleave` and `mouseenter` events on the canvas element.

A third is to actually use the mouse buttons. When mouse button is held down on the canvas element you set a flag so `mousemove` events are considered.

This will keep listening until the mouse button is released. If you release it outside canvas and is using the canvas `mouseup` event it won't be detected. Therefor you should listen to the *window*'s `mouseup` event which will trigger in either case.

This also goes for `mousemove` events. Using the window event will allow you to record positions outside canvas. If you don't want to do this you can use canvas' `mousemove` which will clip at the canvas' boundaries.

It boils down to:

Use the `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup` events in combination and you'll be fine. All these events delivers `clientX` and `clientY` for mouse positions.

And if I may - you can also test by going to my [easyCanvas project](http://easyCanvasJS.com/) and run the sample:
[Sample - mouse event details](http://abdiassoftware.com/easycanvas/sample_details.html)

This will show you details for mouse down, move and up (the details are extended with other information, but you can at least verify mouse positions -  do a click without moving and you see the mouse position is exactly the same).

Comment: Thanks to all of you above. Looking at it now - you make a lot of sense of it. I will revert once I rewrite it to my requirements.

Comment: I was trying to employ [this technique](http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/february/an-example-of-the-html5-canvas-ispointinpath-function.html), but I have a lot more shapes 1000+, which is why I want the redraw to happen only when the mouse stops, without a button event, not when it is moving...

Comment: @HanningtonMambo with that many shapes you'll need to isolate the area you test by f.ex. adding a bounding rectangle to the shape at creation (see quad-tree). Then you check coordinates and only the shapes with a rectangle containing the x/y position will be checked with isPointInPath. If you have many overlapping shapes also include priority by using an array which you check from end to start. But I believe this outside the scope of the original question. I would suggest you up-vote/accept answers for question if any helped with the problem and open a new one specific for this new problem.

Comment: I was actually on the path of isolation (creating), I was only still stuck with this movement problem. let me create another feed. Thanks, Ken.

Comment: Follow-on question to this is posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772424/detecting-irregular-shape)...

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265076/how-can-i-determine-start-and-stop-points-for-mouse-cursor?rq=1) is splendid, Durden81! Computing time difference rather than mouse positions does the deal for me. Then get the point when you know you have stopped.

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/6czap/74/

I hope i helped with this :)

```
$("div").mousemove(function(e){
   var pageCoords = "( " + e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY + " )";
  var clientCoords = "( " + e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY + " )";
  $("span:first").text("( e.pageX, e.pageY ) : " + pageCoords);
  $("span:last").text("( e.clientX, e.clientY ) : " + clientCoords);
});
```

Comment: He's not using jQuery, and this really has nothing to do with the question anyway.