# Detecting irregular Shape

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, quadtree

Leading up from this question [Detecting mouse coordinates with precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678288/detecting-mouse-coordinates-with-precision/17679559#17679559), I have learnt quite a bit in the past few days. Here are what I picked as best learning resources on this topic:

1. http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space/
2. http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/quadtrees-r1303
3. http://jsfiddle.net/2dchA/2/

The code in (3) works in JSFiddle but breaks at this section in my testing environment (VS2012):

```
var myTree = new Quadtree({
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: 400,
  height: 300
});
```

with the message Quadtree is undefined in IE. FF & Chrome just gloss over it and display an empty page. I couldn't sort it out. **Question 1: Can someone help out with that?**

My main question:
I have a region (parcels of land like a map) with about 1500 parcels drawn in html5, not jpg or png images. It is a lot of lines of code to complete that but the rendering is great, so I am keeping it that way. I intend to have a mouseover event tell me which parcel I am standing on when the mouse stops. As you will see in the previous question referred my previous attempts were not impressive. Based on the learning I have been doing, and thanks to Ken J's answer/comments, I would like to go with this new approach of slicing up my canvas into say 15 quads of 100 objects each. However, I would like some guidance before I take another wild dive the wrong way.

**Question 2:** Should I slice it up at creation or should the slicing happen when the mouse is over a region, ie, trail the mouse? The latter sounds better to me but I think I can do with some advice and, if possible, some start out code. The quadtree concept is completely new to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can't help with question 1.

You should definitely build the tree as early as possible, given that the objective is to get the page to respond as quick as possible once the user clicks somewhere.

Keep the tree for as long as the user interacts with the 2d area. Updating a quad tree shouldn't be too hard, so even if the area changes contents, you should be able to reuse the existing tree (just update it).

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that your draw area is well know i see no advantage in a QuadTree over a spacial hash function. This function will give you an integer out of an (x,y) point.

```
var blocWidth   = 20;
var blocHeight  = 20;
var blocsPerLine = ( 0 | ( worldWidth / blocWidth) ) + 1 ; 
function hashPoint(x,y) {
   return ( 0 | (x/blocWidth)) + blocsPerLine*(0|(y/blocHeight));
}
```

once you built that, hash all your parcels within an array :

```
parcelHash = [];

function addHash(i,p) {
   if (!parcelHash[i]) { parcelHash[i]=[ p ]; return; }
   if (parcelHash[i].indexOf(p) != -1 ) return;
   parcelHash[i].push(p);
}

function hashParcel (p) {
     var thisHash = hashPoint(p.x,p.y); // upper left
     addHash( thisHash, p);
     thisHash = hashPoint(p.x+width, p.y); // upper right
     addHash(thisHash, p);
     thisHash = hashPoint(p.x, p.y+p.height); // lower left
     addHash(thisHash, p);
     thisHash = hashPoint(p.x+width, p.y+p.height); // lower right
     addHash(thisHash, p);         
};

for (var i=0; i<allParcels.length; i++) { hashParcel(allParcels[i]) };
```

now if you have a mouse position, you can retrieve all the parcels in the
same block with :

```
  function getParcels(x,y) {  
       var thisHash = hashPoint(x,y); 
       return parcelHash[thisHash]; 
    }
```

Comment: Vincent, is your code presuming rectangular shapes (x,y)? I am not sure I am following your suggestion: my shapes are irregular parcels of land with too many 'moveTo(x,y)' and 'lineTo(x,y)', which intersect to draw a single piece...

Comment: Thats a surprise because as I understand it, the parcels should always have the same width:height ratio. Are you sure it is Quad Trees and not k-d trees (or something similar)?

Comment: Actually, it is quite like googlemap, only instead of countries I have parcels of land. they are rarely regular shapes this side of the world :) demarcations could be rivers, hills, etc. I just checked up k-d trees and I think it is not what I need. k-d is multi-dimensional. My case is simple 2d, only irregular edges.

Comment: The k-d trees can be used in any number of dimensions - two included :) But again - doesn't Quad Trees require regular parcels? Otherwise it's just something else?

Answer (score 0):

I'll just give you few tips in addition to what others have said.

*... have a mouseover event tell me which parcel I am standing on ...*

From your other messages I conclude that parcels will have irregular shapes. Quadtrees in general work with rectangles, so you'd have to calculate the *bounding rectangle* around the shape of the parcel and insert that rectangle in the quadtree. Then are when you want to determine whether mouse is over a parcel, you'll query the quadtree which will give you a set of parcels that *might* be under the mouse, but you'll have to then do a more precise check on your own to see if it indeed is.

*... when the mouse stops.*

From your other questions I saw that you try to detect when the mouse has "stopped". Maybe you should look at it this way: mouse cursor is never moving, it's *teleporting* around the screen from previous point to next. It's always stopped, never moving. This might seem a bit philosophical, but it'll keep your code simpler. You should definitely be able to achieve what you intended without any setTimeout checks.

*... slicing up my canvas into say 15 quads of 100 objects each.*
*... Should I slice it up at creation or should the slicing happen when the mouse is over a region*

You won't (and can't) do slicing, quadtree implementation does that automatically (that's its purpose) when you insert or remove items from it (note that moving the item is actually removing then re-inserting it).

I didn't look into the implementation of quadtree that you're using, but here are two MX-CIF quadtree implementations in case that one doesn't work out for you:

- https://github.com/pdehn/jsQuad
- https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts/tree/master/src/jsts/index/quadtree

The problem in question 1 probably happens because jsfiddle (http) page is trying access quadtree.js which is on https

Comment: Thanks for the insights bgr. I ended up with the timer for 'mousestopped' as referred earlier. And while the quadtree is really exciting, I found I couldn't use it for my case. I grouped my shapes into hundreds by code; works fast enough for my purposes & deadline. I will definitely explore this a more options later.